# Gradle: often I need to reload/re-download project dependencies because they get deleted

Tags: gradle

I have several gradle's projects where in `build.gradle` I have defined their dependencies.

I am not able to understand why but for some reason after some time the jars download by `gradle` needs to be re-downloaded.
I open one of my projects in idea or eclipse (depend on the project) and all the dependencies are missing and I can't compile the project until I download them again.

Any reason for this?
The `gradle` cache has an expiration time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Gradle periodically cleans up the local cache and removes unused artifacts. It's a feature introduced with Gradle 4.10 [Cleanup of caches and distributions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home:cache_cleanup). There is an open issue on GitHub to make retention times configurable: [Make periodic cache cleanup retention times configurable #7018](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7018).